# Close reason request: "See a professional"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In some areas, [medical](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) being a good example, people may ask for help related to an issue or idea that has the potential to be *dangerous*, or even ***life-threatening***.

I propose the following close reason be added:

> We recommend you seek the opinion of a trained professional for this or similar matters.

This is assuming that helping people do dangerous things *is* on-topic **and** *is* a good idea.

Comment: Would this apply to psychological troubles as well? How about law? What about needing to hire a professional to fix something?

Comment: This really seems too specific and narrow to be worth its own custom close reason.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 Thus why I didn't say just "See a doctor". [This answer](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/437/15) included a large disclaimer. But perhaps the question itself should be closed as "dangerous".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the premise of a question is ill-advised, you should explain your concerns in a comment and either help fix the question or vote to close it as off topic (or whatever reason applies). But creating an explicit close reason for this is overkill.

Not all medical questions are categorically *off topic.* We don't want to create a situation where everyone is being directed to rubber stamp these questions automatically as a problem. Creating an explicit close reason has a tendency to do that; i.e. "Notice: If you see a question like this, it ***should*** be closed."

There are only so many slots for custom 'close' reasons, so the frequency of this problem would have to great enough to warrant an administrative change like this.

If you encounter a question that is not a good fit for this site, leave a comment describing how to either help improve the post or close it. If the problem becomes frequent enough to warrant more drastic measures, we can talk about it then. But for the time being, err towards *discussing* these issue with users asking for help instead of creating a lot of unnecessary "rules" before there's an actual problem affecting the performance of the site.

Comment: "If the problem becomes frequent enough to warrant more drastic measures, we can talk about it then." <= Will do. :)

Comment: I updated the tag wiki for [tag:personal-care] to reflect parts of this answer. Would you please let me know your thoughts on it? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know. I think that any emergency situation that would warrant a close reason like this shouldn't be on-topic in the first place.

If we say that a problem with only one solution, or a problem where the most efficient solution is the most common solution isn't a lifehack, then we could just close these types of questions as being off-topic.

For example: There is no lifehack for a broken bone, it either gets reset or it doesn't.

Comment: I agree. (Perhaps renaming the tag might help it not *sound like* it includes medical advice? Not sure.)

Answer (score 6):

This is a tough one. Though I don't think we need one. In the examples in the question and comments, the boundaries are pretty clear; seek medical attention, hire an electrician.
In many cases however, the line gets blurred so the average person cannot distinguish when to use such a proposed closing reason anymore.

*To be more clear; you'll have to be an expert in a certain field before you can judge whether a professional needs to be consulted instead of offering a lifehack... Since the voting/reviewing systems can't only select people from a certain profession, this can never be succesfully implemented.*

Comment: Some things are obvious, Like I shot myself in the foot what is a good hack for the bleeding, or What's a hack to stop that grinding noise in my brakes. Some questions are a little surreal in the lack of common sense the OP has and it does not particularly require in expert in the field to cast the first close vote or say go see a professional.